# Parse PKCS #7 SSL Certificate Chain (.p7b) without private key?

Tags: c#, security, ssl, certificate, pkcs#7

I have a PKCS #7, signed, .p7b file which contains an X509 SSL certificate and the intermediate and root CA certs it was signed with. I need to use C# to parse the .p7b file, pull out the SSL certificate, and pull some values off of it (expiry date, DN, etc).

I've tried reading it as an X509 certificate like so:

```
//certContent is a byte array with the p7b file contents
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certContent);
```

That works fine with a regular .cer certificate, but throws a `CryptographicException` when used with a .p7b certificate. This is because the .p7b contains the entire certificate chain.

I've also tried parsing it as a `SignedCms` object, then iterating through the certificate chain and pulling out my SSL certificate:

```
SignedCms certContainer = new SignedCms();
certContainer.Decode(certContent);
foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in certConatiner.Certificates)
{
     ...
}
```

However that throws an exception on `Decode` saying `ASN1 bad tag value met`. After some searching, I believe that is because I do not have the private key which was used to create the certificate and/or sign the certificate.

Does anyone know how I can parse this .p7b certificate chain using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot. I opened up the .p7b file and realized it was just base64 on the inside. I pulled out the base64, decoded that, then parsed that as a signed CMS and all is well.

```
String content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(certContent);
String base64Content = content.Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "").Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
byte[] decodedContent = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Content);
SignedCms certContainer = new SignedCms();
certContainer.Decode(decodedContent);
```

Comment: This is exatly what I am having problem with. Could you please share the part of the code which retrieves bytes from database and then convert it into a X509Certificate? Thanks